# Visual Basic 2015 (press any key after loading)

Tags: vb.net

i wanna ask for help for my vb. I am trying to make a loading screen that when the progress bar hits 100 there will be a message but not a message box that shows (Press any key to continue) just like in games. I did my own coding but it jumps straight to form3 and the console does not appear.

```
    `ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If`
```

Comment: There's not much point using `Console` in a Windows Forms application.  That's not going to display anything in your GUI.  You'd need to do something like show a `Label` that was previously hidden and then handle the `KeyPress` event of the form.

Comment: Also, don't `Hide` a form unless you specifically want that form to still exist and be able to be shown again later.  If you are done with a form then close it.

Comment: If you're using a GUI, then you shouldn't be using a console. You have a conceptual flaw (you're doing something very wrong from the start). Remove everything that refers to `Console` and try again.

Comment: Ow okay, i understand  thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achive what you are looking for this could be a possible solution:

- Don't use a MsgBox, instead create a new form that looks like a `MsgBox` and call it when the progress bar is full

This is the Main class of the code (the class calling the `MsgBox like` form):

```
Public Class Main

    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        progressBarIncrement()
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub progressBarIncrement()
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        Thread.Sleep(20) '20 milliseconds of sleep
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            FormPressKey.Show()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            progressBarIncrement()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

and this is the second form, that is called when the progress bar is complete!

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Me.Close()
    GC.Collect()
End Sub
```

As you can notice I created a recursive function in order to increase the `ProgressBar value` and check it through every iteration.

I also added some sleep between every increments, in order to simulate a loading progress bar.

**N.B.** If you want to use `Thread.Sleep(time_in_milliseconds)` you have to add on the top of your code `Imports System.Threading`

Comment: Thank you very much @Simo its really a big help i appreciate it.. 

after I read the previous comments of jmcilhinney and Ken White. I manage to do it my own, though there's a glitch on my code that even the progress bar is not yet 100% complete if i press the button it goes right away to form3. Heres my code

Comment: In my examples this case is impossible, because the `MsgBox Like Form` isn't called untile the `progressbar` is 100% complete

Answer (score -1):

Though theres a glitch on my code i manage to do it heheh thanks for your help guys. :)

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    PictureBox2.Visible = False
    Label1.Visible = False
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Label1.Visible = True
        Label2.Visible = False
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

    If Keys.Space Then
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry about the pictureboxes i used them for the loading splash screen